# Limit number of characters in input where jquery numpad is used

Tags: html, jquery

How would I limit number of characters in input where jquery keypad is used?

HTML

```
<input id="num-input" type="text" maxlength="3" disabled>
```

JQUERY

```
var $numInput;

$(function() {
  initKeyboard($('#numeric-keyboard'), $('#num-input'));

  $('#num-input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    $('#event').text('key: '+e.keyCode);
  });

  $('#back').on('click', onBackBtn);
  $('#forward').on('click', onForwardBtn);
});

function onBackBtn() {
   $('input').first().focus(); 
}

function onForwardBtn() {
   $('input').last().focus(); 
}

function initKeyboard($keyboard, $input) {
  $numInput = $input;

   $keyboard.on('click', '.key', onKeyPress); 
}

function onKeyPress(e) {
  var keyValue = $(this).text();

  if(keyValue.toLowerCase() === 'delete') {
     keyValue = 8; 
  } else if(keyValue === '') {
     return; 
  } else {
     keyValue = keyValue.charCodeAt(0); 
  }

  var e = $.Event("keydown");
  e.which = keyValue;
  e.keyCode = keyValue;

  $numInput.trigger(e);

  if(keyValue !== 8) {
    $numInput.val( $numInput.val() + $(this).text() );
  } else {
    $numInput.val( $numInput.val().slice(0, -1) );
  }
}
```

maxlenght is ignorred, I attempted to add if clause to `$numInput.val( $numInput.val() + $(this).text() );` this part of the code with var max=3; but again no luck.

I have also tried with out of this code script to limit number of characters for that input but again jquery overtakes it and keep adding characters.

I need t set limit of 3 characters to it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`#num-input` is disabled, maybe maxlength need to be set in `#numeric-keyboard` field?

Comment: why you presume #numeric-keyboard is a field? its a div displaying keys of jquery keyboard.